# Chef: Update gem on client needed by cookbook during chef-client

Tags: chef-infra

I've recently updated an Ubuntu box that is running as a chef client. When I try to chef-client the server, I get the following error:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_database[myapp_prod]'
================================================================================


RuntimeError
------------
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.29 but the client library is 5.6.15.


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/cache/chef/cookbooks/database/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb:29:in `load_current_resource'
```

How do I re-install the gem that the cookbook is relying on here? I've tried updating the system gem to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef have it's own ruby embedded, best bet:

```
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem uninstall mysql
```